# Default scroll tooltip messing up as of Marshmallow

Tags: android, tooltip, scrollbar, material-design, android-4.4-kitkat

We have a scroll bar similar to Android Clock App 'Select Cities' activity, but its breaking now that we're making a Marshmallow supported build.

On M it was the wrong size and wrong width. We fixed that with an M-specific theme.

On L it is fine

On K it sits in the middle of the screen and spins, without following the scroll tap target. We guess that we could set a K specific theme too, but not sure how we would get it to follow the scroll bar.

What gives?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using:

```
<item name="android:fastScrollOverlayPosition">aboveThumb</item>
```

change it to:

```
<item name="android:fastScrollOverlayPosition">atThumb</item>
```

Worked for me. For some reason "aboveThumb" doesn't play nice with pre-L devices.